# Time difference between two dates showing one hour less

Tags: php, datetime, diff

An user subscription is valid for **24 hours**. I want to show the remaining time in hours & minutes.

```
$today = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone('Europe/Brussels'));
$date_created = new DateTime($arr["ins_date_created"]); // 2019-12-24 23:06:42
$diff = $date_created->diff($today); 

echo ($diff->format("%hu %i' valid"));
echo '<br>'.$today->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') .'<br>'. $date_created->format('Y-m-d H:i:s').'<br>';
```

The output is:
2u 3' valid
2019-12-25 02:09:57
2019-12-24 23:06:42

The first problem is that he gives one hour less => it must be **3u 3' valid**

The second problem is that I want to show: **still 20u 57' valid**

Someone who can help me?

Thanks!

Comment: probably the two dates has different timezone, but you haven't posted all the varaibles declaration so i'm just supposing

Comment: Where can I find the other timezone variables?

Comment: new DateTimeZone('Europe/Brussels') the 'Europe/Brussels' is the timezone, the other date where is builted?

Comment: It comes from the database.

Comment: post the database where you build it

Comment: Why not do the date diff on the `select`? Not sure what your DB is but it'd probably be a better solution.

Comment: Thanks! It works! I'm now using `TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,i.ins_date_created,NOW()) as ins_date_created_minuut` and it works. I think the hour difference is an php problem in some versions.

Answer (score 0):

`$today` is in Brussels local time and `$date_created` is in currently configured PHP local time. Since the second value is not an absolute time you'll get different results, all of them correct, whenever it changes:

```
$a = '2019-12-25 02:09:57';
$b = '2019-12-24 23:06:42';

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Brussels');
$today = new DateTime($a, new DateTimeZone('Europe/Brussels'));
$date_created = new DateTime($b);
var_dump($date_created->diff($today)->format("%hu %i' valid"));

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
$today = new DateTime($a, new DateTimeZone('Europe/Brussels'));
$date_created = new DateTime($b);
var_dump($date_created->diff($today)->format("%hu %i' valid"));

date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Tokyo');
$today = new DateTime($a, new DateTimeZone('Europe/Brussels'));
$date_created = new DateTime($b);
var_dump($date_created->diff($today)->format("%hu %i' valid"));
```

```
string(11) "3u 3' valid"
string(11) "2u 3' valid"
string(12) "11u 3' valid"
```

If you expect `3u 3` that means that both dates are in Brussels time so don't forget to tell PHP about it. If you don't really need to mix time zones, I suggest you configure it at application (or at least session) level so you can omit the second parameter in `DateTime` constructor.